# Can I edit a form in the user's drive that i've already created and shared with me through my add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

This is the function for modify the form in the user´s drive once the user's installed the add-on. THe add-on creates a folder in the user's root folder and the folder is shared with me.

```
function crearformulario() {

var formid = "1oN6kfpgqPNGiI-tc_8bUUGjcXKFhoRR3rwfq0Z1pSv8";
FormApp.openById(formid).setRequireLogin(false);
var folderid = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MOTOR")
.getRange("B1").getValue();

//COPYING THE ORIGINAL FORM TO A USER'S FOLDER
var archivos = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid).getFiles();
var control6 = "NO"
while (archivos.hasNext()) {
var archivo = archivos.next();
var nombrear = archivo.getName();
if(nombrear =="Test de Convivencia"){var control6 = "SI"; var modeloid = 
archivo.getId();}}

if(control6 =="NO"){

var modelo = DriveApp.getFileById(formid);
var copiamodelo = modelo.makeCopy(modelo.getName(), 
DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid)).setName("Test de Convivencia");
var modeloid = copiamodelo.getId();
var carpeta = ss.getSheetByName("MOTOR").getRange("B2").setValue(modeloid);
}

//PICKING DATA FROM THE USER'S SPREADSHEET
var alumnos =[]
var datapre = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var data = datapre.getSheetByName("DATOS").getDataRange().getValues();
for (var b=1;b<data.length;b++){
var alumno = data[b][0];
if (alumno !=""){alumnos.push(alumno);}}
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Seguimos Trabajando...");
//CHANGIN ITEMS IN THE FORM
var items = FormApp.openById(modeloid).getItems();
var itemini = items[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues(alumnos);
//CALLING ANOTHER FUNCTION
progreso2();
}
```

Is anything forbidden in this function? I've already tested and it works for me in "test as add-on". I really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: When the user installs the Add-on, your code is evaluated, and the needed permissions are asked for from the user.  If your code is creating a Form in the users Drive, and then editing it, the Add-on will ask for the permissions to do that.  Of course, the user could refuse to accept, and cancel.  So, the answer is, if the user that installs the Add-on gives permission, then there will be no problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sandy. It works now. And sorry for the tags Rubén.